# Media queries aren't working in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, mobile, dreamweaver

I manage a website that is built in Dreamweaver (terrible, I know). The website is not mobile-responsive and so I am attempting to write queries to see if it can be fixed. I found the site's breakpoints through breakpoint Tester and used the code below in a separate CSS file (I also tried it on the main stylesheet). Nothing happens. Can anyone offer any insight as to what I'm missing?

*Note: I'm somewhat new so I apologize in advance for any errors.*

**HTML:**

```
<link href="queries.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 1824px)">
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (max-width: 1824px) {

}

/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1224px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 768px) {

}

/* Portrait phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 321px) {

}
```

Comment: Are you missing the `<>` to enclose the link tag in the HTML?

Comment: Do normal declarations work in the queries.css file? ie. ones that are not inside media queries?

Comment: Nope, I have the brackets - I just took them out here because for some reason Stack Overflow deletes copy contained in brackets. So it really should be: <link href="queries.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 1824px)">

Comment: I would avoid using breakpoints for specific sizes like that, and instead include them when the layout breaks. Try writing them as `@media all and (max-width: 980px) {}` Also, is your path correct for the stylesheet?

Comment: Have you tried testing in a real browser or only in DW's so-called WYSIWYG view?

Comment: @SamWillis, I'll try that, thanks. And Quentin, yes, I've tried in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add a viewport meta tag in the head of your website. It defines the actual width of your screen that the CSS reads.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag